# Laravel 5.2 - Has One through or custom attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So here are my models:

- `EmployerHours` belongsTo `Report`
- `Report` belongsTo `Employer`

There were many places where we were doing `$employerHour->report->employer` to get the employer tied to the `EmployerHour`. (keep in mind I do not have the ability to change the schema). I decided to do the following on the `EmployerHour` model:

```
/**
 * Attribute for retrieving the Employer directly from employer hours
 * @return App\Models\Employer
 */
public function getEmployerAttribute()
{
    return $this->report->employer;
}
```

This almost seems like a hack. However, there are many times where this occurs and this has become useful. I was thinking there MUST be a `hasOneThrough` relationship but it doesn't seem so. Is this the correct way to be doing this or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

There is always a way :)

You can achieve this by joining tables. An example would be:

```
// EmployerHour.php

public function employer()
{

    return Employer

        ::select('employers.*')

        ->join('reports', 'employers.id', '=', 'reports.employer_id')

        ->join('employerhours', 'reports.id', '=', 'employerhours.report_id')

        ->where('employerhours.id', $this->id);

}
```

Maybe you need to change the column names used in this example.